# How to connect with social websites from java application?

Tags: java

when we use these api

- For Twitter: twitter4j
- For Facebook: fb-java-api
- For Linkedin: linkedin-j

we will be redirected to particular site
(if i use linkedin-j, it will redirect to linkedin and so to all api) and get user information like user name and password 
to verify them to allow access. but my question is having username and password only once, we have to collect all the details from facebook,linkedin,twitter etc.

Answer (score 1):

You usually get a secret token after you've successfully authenticated with the sites. Store it until you log out and use it for your API calls. You do not (shouldn't) get username and password from the site, if the user uses the site's login dialog.

Comment: what you say is correct but using java web application i provide interface for the user to provide their credentials, using those i try to fetch information from social websites like facebook,twitter etc. Hope i am clear. so using above api we are redirected to their web site instead we need to access theri website and collect information about the logged in user who is logged in java application

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use any web application, that takes *my* credentials and uses them to log into *my* social media accounts. Never ever.

Comment: hope you got what i am trying to say. it is just a try i want to give it, may i am not going to ask neither you nor anybody else. suggest if you have solution.